# Comma Use Before And

Tags: commas, comma-splices

Should a comma be used before "and" in this line?

> Give in to the darkness and you'll leave this world prematurely.

Similar line, same question:

> Always do what is right and you can keep them at bay.

Comment: The second half of each example sentence is a consequence of the first half. You might read each sentence as having an implicit *If you* at the start which turn the *and* into *then*.  A comma before *and* might instead be read as making the first half of each into an imperative.

Answer (score 1):

Comma is optional. Comma is used in written language to indicate a pause in spoken language. There are other pose indicators such as semicolon and colon etc. In your two example sentences, even without the comma meaning is not lost. Commas become necessary in longwinding sentences with very long clauses, otherwise the reader loses track of the information conveyed in the sentences.

Your example sentences are fine without the commas.